# Asp.Net Web Api Allow Url Encoded Forward/Backward Slash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a string with some special characters to my Asp.Net Web Api controller. However, Asp.Net can't seem to resolve the url encoded string. Sending something like "A%2F223%2F4" is the encoding for "A/223/4" and the same also doesn't work for backward slashes. It does work for other special characters though. Is there any way to get this working? Or is it possible to turn the automatic decoding off, so that I can do it manually?

This is my functions inside my controller:

```
[HttpGet, Route("getByArtNr/{articleNr}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByArtNr(string articleNr)
{
    Article article = dbContext.Article.Where(x => x.ArtNr == articleNr).FirstOrDefault();
    if(article == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(article);
}
```

Example request:
http://localhost:54282/api/v1/article/getByArtNr/A%2F223%2F4/

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a string which has `/` (slashes) in it, we can use the `wildcard parameters` in the route. Something like this:

`Route("getByArtNr/{*articleNr}")`

This will allow for a chunk of a URL with multiple `/` characters to be read as a single parameter.

Hope it helps.